# Why did changing <> to != cause my query to take twice as long to run?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

As far as I know the two are synonymous. However, changing `<>` to `!=` increases my duration from 9-10 secs to 18-19 secs.

my query looks like this

```
select cast(Item.type as char), (IFNULL(SUM(IFNULL(Item.amount, 0)),0) + IFNULL(Refund.amount ,0)) *-1 
from Item
join Billing on Billing.id = Item.bill_id
join Payment_Item pi on Item.id = pi.Item_id
left join Payment p on p.id = pi.payment_id
left join Refund on Refund.type = Item.type
     where Billing.year = 2020
     and Billing.Code <> 075
     group by Item.type
```

If I change `Billing.Code <> 075` to `Billing.Code != 075` then my duration is increasing dramatically

Just for more info: Explain doesn't show any difference between the query using `<>` and the query using `!=`

*Edited query to simplify

**It's not longer taking twice as long. I'm not sure why, I didn't make any changes and it was doing it consistently before.

Comment: The second part of this is definitely too broad for this site - there could be a million things you might or might not know about query optimisation. The first part is theoretically answerable, but you need to [edit] to provide some more details about the query for anyone to do anything other than guess - ideally, a [mcve] with schema definition, sample data, and the exact SQL.

Comment: Can we see a query plan for each form of the `SELECT`?

Comment: This is a fairly complicated query. Can you condense it down to a [mre], or at the very least share what your database looks like so that people can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I think it is plausible that MySQL detected the new version (<>) as a different query and compiled a new explain plan based on current statistics, whereas your existing query (!=) is using a previous known explain plan. This would also explain why you see the numbers converge as eventually both queries were optimized to the same plan. However, I am just speculating.

Answer (score -1):

you can try creating indexes for some of your tables, indexes are usually done on the shared attribute for the tables where you are comparing, for example to see if the shared attribute between two tables in a query are equal.

```
CREATE INDEX <index_name> ON <tablename>(<attribute_name>);
```

Where the attribute name is usually the primary key of the table.

Hope this helped

Comment: What does your answer have to do with `!=` taking twice as long as `<>` ?

Comment: quoting from his question "Are there other things that dramatically improve or impair performance that might not be common knowledge?" that is why i have said what i said he didn't specify just trying to help so do not know why you voted my answer down. .